Responsiveness with tailwind and resolution
In a simple test with Tailwind, on a screen recommended at 1920x1080 resolution with a scale of 150% (default by Windows), the text is displaying as yellow instead of green.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="lg:text-yellow-400 xl:text-red-400 2xl:text-green-400">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>



Why does lg:text-yellow-400 take precedence over 2xl:text-green-400? After all, the resolution is originally 1920x1080, which falls above the 2xl range.

In the browser, using the zoom function manipulates the width and height of the window.
If you set the browser to 150% zoom on a 1920 px wide monitor, you've effectively reduced the original width to 2/3 of its size.
1920px / 3 * 2 = 1280px

And 1280 px corresponds to the formatting of lg:text-yellow-400. Tailwind perfectly tracks the zoom.
Extra: The width is minimally influenced by the presence of the scrollbar. This typically subtracts about 10-12 px from it.
Calculator
I quickly wrote you a calculator where you input the monitor width, specify the zoom percentage, and it calculates the new effective width for you.


function calculateNewWidth() {
  const originalWidth = document.getElementById("originalWidth").value;
  const zoomPercentage = document.getElementById("zoomPercentage").value;

  // Calculate new width
  const newWidth = originalWidth / (zoomPercentage / 100);

  document.getElementById("result").textContent = `New Width: ${newWidth}px`;
}
<div>
  <label for="originalWidth">Original Width (px):</label>
  <input type="number" id="originalWidth" min="0" required value="1920"> px
</div>

<div>
  <label for="zoomPercentage">Zoom Percentage:</label>
  <input type="number" id="zoomPercentage" min="0" required value="150"> %
</div>

<button onclick="calculateNewWidth()">Calculate</button>

<p id="result"></p>



So you're asking the browser to make the content larger. It achieves this by pretending that the webpage is being viewed on a smaller monitor instead of the width of your actual monitor, and then stretches the content obtained in this way to fit your screen. But the website will think that you're actually using a smaller screen.

thank you, so in general we can do nothing about it, if the  os default a scaling
